# How to find the generic initial ideal?

Tags: commutative-algebra, monomial-ideals

Here is an example from Ezra Miller's book: *Combinatorial Commutative Algebra*, pp. 26-27.

Let $f,g\in k[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4]$ be generic forms of degree $d$ and $e$. The generic initial ideal of $I=\langle f,g\rangle$ for both the lexicographic order and the inverse lexicographic order when $(d,e)=(2,2)$: the ideal $J=\operatorname{gin}_{\operatorname{lex}}(I)$ is $(x_2^4,x_1x_3^2,x_1x_2,x_1^2)$, 
the ideal $J=\operatorname{gin}_{\operatorname{revlex}}(I)$ is $(x_2^3,x_1x_2,x_1^2)$.

How to find it?

Comment: How is $\operatorname{gin}_{\operatorname{lex}}$ defined?

Comment: Rough speaking,lex is a kind of order <，the initial ideal in$_<$(gI) as a function of g is a constant on a Zariski open subset U in GL$_n$ is called a gin for I and <.I think it is a mainly part of the initial ideal,but I just learn it some days ago,so cannot say anything deeply.

Comment: Crossposted to MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93829/how-to-find-the-generic-initial-ideal

Answer (score 0):

You can use a software such as [Macaulay2](http://habanero.math.cornell.edu:3690/). [here](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~erman/615/Mayes_Gins.pdf)  are some examples.